# Getting Login Issue for New User with CoSign SOAP API

Tags: cosign-api

I have created the new user on the CoSign server. I am getting the following response (User password expired) while logging using the `ValidateCredentials` method.

```
Array
(
    [Success] => 
    [ErrData] => Array
        (
            [Message] => User password expired.
            [Module] => ValidateCredentials
            [Code] => -36
            [InnerCode] => -1878916637
        )

)
```

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1):

This error means that the user’s password has expired, and you need to reset it

Comment: I know user's password has expired but this error message is coming for all new users. If i activate the user using the 'UserActivate' Api, Error message "user activation failed" displayed rather i am passing all three parameters  Username,Password and NewPassword.                              
   
I have also changed the password many times using setPassword Api.